# Tkinter Listbox How to tell if an item is selected

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to create a simple GUI that allows the user to press a button, which will delete an entry from a shown Listbox. However, the console throws an error if no entry is selected, so how would I determine if the user has selected an entry. Here's my code:

```
selection = self.recipe_list.curselection()
    if not selection is None:
        self.recipe_list.delete(selection)
    else:
        print("Nothing to delete!")
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning `None` like you're checking for, it returns an empty string, `""`. Check for that as follows:

```
if selection:
    self.recipe_list.delete(selection)
else:
    print("Nothing to delete!")
```

Answer (score 3):

According with

**Tkinter reference: a GUI for Python**

Methods on listbox objects include:

**.curselection()**

Returns a tuple containing the line numbers of the selected element or elements, counting from 0.

If nothing is selected, returns an empty tuple.

So you can do somenthing like this

```
if self.MyListbox.curselection():
        index = self.MyListbox.curselection()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not self.lstb.curselection() is ():
```